# Alpha Beta Pruning Algorithm Java

Tags: java, alpha-beta-pruning

I've been working on the code for alpha-beta pruning for a Connect Four game and I can't seem to get it right. I thought I implemented it correctly at first, but the algorithm would return the column 1 every time. I have two `int`s val and `nodeVal` that I use to determine my alpha and beta values. When I instantiate them as 0 inside my `alphaBetaPruning()` algorithm, the column that is returned by the `alphaBetaSearch()` method is always 1. If I instantiate these values outside of the `alphaBetaPruning()` algorithm, the `alphaBetaSearch()` algorithm results in a `Null Pointer Exception`

.

Note: the `ConnectFourBoard` class holds the best child of a board state.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public class ConnectFourPlayer
{
  private final int columns = 7;

  private char currentPlayer;
  private char computer = 'C';
  private char opponent = 'P';
  private int depth = 8;
  //private int val = 0;
  //private int nodeVal = 0;
  private int minMax;

  /**
  * Constructor method creates the computer
  * player.
  */

  public ConnectFourPlayer()
  {

  }

  /**
  * Method returns the number of children
  * given a board state. 
  */

  public int numberOfChildren(ConnectFourBoard board)
  {
    int count = 0;
    //count number of columns with empty slots
    for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++) 
    {
      for (int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
      {
        if ( board.board[row][col] == ' ')
        {
          count++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }

  /**
  * Method generates the children of a given
  * board state and stores them in the array
  * boardChildren[]. The array boardChildren
  * is the size of the number of possible 
  * children.
  */

  public void generateChildren(ConnectFourBoard board)
  {

    board.boardChildren = new ConnectFourBoard[this.numberOfChildren(board)];
    int childNumber = 0;
    for (int boardCol = 0; boardCol < columns; boardCol++)
    {
      for (int boardRow = 0; boardRow < 6; boardRow++)
      {
        if ( board.board[boardRow][boardCol] == ' ' )
        {
          ConnectFourBoard childBoard = new ConnectFourBoard();
          for(int row = 0; row < 6; row++)
          {
            for(int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
            {
              childBoard.board[row][col] = board.board[row][col];
            }
          }
          childBoard.row = boardRow;
          childBoard.column = boardCol;
          childBoard.board[boardRow][boardCol] = currentPlayer;
          board.boardChildren[childNumber] = childBoard;
          childNumber++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * Method implements the alphaBetaPruning algorithm. 
  * Returns the column that corresponds to that 
  * column with the highest alphaBetaPruning value. 
  */

  public int alphaBetaSearch(ConnectFourBoard board)
  {
    minMax = 1;
    currentPlayer = computer;
    alphaBetaPruning(board, this.depth, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return board.best.column;
  }

  /**
  * Method returns the static evaluation function value of the
  * best possible move that will maximize the computer player's 
  * move value and also minimize the opponent's move value, 
  * given a depth limit.
  */

  public int alphaBetaPruning(ConnectFourBoard board, int depth, int alpha, int beta)
  {
    //create StaticEvaluationFunction object to evaluate each possible move
    StaticEvaluationFunction evaluator = new StaticEvaluationFunction();
    int val = 0;
    int nodeVal = 0;
    //check if the computer is in a goal state
    if(board.gameOver() == 'C')
    {
      board.best = null;
      return evaluator.evaluate(board, this.currentPlayer);
    }
    //check if depth limit was reached
    if(depth == 0)
    {
      board.best = null;
      return evaluator.evaluate(board, this.currentPlayer);
    }
    //fill the boardChildren[] array with all children of the current board
    this.generateChildren(board);
    int width = this.numberOfChildren(board);
    //check if the current board state has any children
    if(width == 0)
    {
      board.best = null;
      return evaluator.evaluate(board, this.currentPlayer);
    }
    else 
    {
      int i = 0;
      boolean prune = false;
      while((!prune) && (i < width))
      {
        //recursive call to alphaBetaPruning()
        val = alphaBetaPruning(board.boardChildren[i], (depth - 1), alpha, beta);
        if(i == 0)
          nodeVal = val;
        //check if current board is a minNode
        if(minNode(board))
        {
          //check current child < smallest child so far
          if(val < nodeVal)
          {
            //set nodeVal to smaller child
            nodeVal = val;
            //set best to this child board
            board.best = board.boardChildren[i];
          }
          //check current child < smallest child so far (local)
          if(val < beta)
            //set beta to smaller child
            beta = val;
        }
        //check if current board is a maxNode
        if(maxNode(board))
        {
          //check current child > biggest child so far
          if(val > nodeVal)
          {
            //set nodeVal to bigger child
            nodeVal = val;
            //set best to this child board
            board.best = board.boardChildren[i];
          }
          //check current child > biggest child so far (local)
          if(val > alpha)
            //set alpha to bigger child
            alpha = val;
        }
        //check max so far > min so far
        if(alpha > beta)
        {
          //prune
          prune = true;
          return nodeVal;
        }
        else i++;
      }//end while  
    }
    return nodeVal;
  }

  /**
  * Method returns true if the given board state is 
  * a max node.
  */

  public boolean maxNode(ConnectFourBoard board)
  {
    if(minMax == 1)
    {
      minMax = 0;
      currentPlayer = opponent;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  /**
  * Method returns true if the given board state is
  * a min node.
  */

  public boolean minNode(ConnectFourBoard board)
  {
    if(minMax == 0)
    {
      minMax = 1;
      currentPlayer = computer;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}





/**Holds the state of the board*/

public class ConnectFourBoard
{
  public final int rows = 6;
  public final int columns = 7;
  public char board[][] = new char[rows][columns];
  public ConnectFourBoard boardChildren[];
  public ConnectFourBoard best;
  public int column;
  public int row;
...
/**
  * Method makes the computer player's move. First, 
  * checks if a move is allowed. If it is, that 
  * slot is set to the computer player's character. 
  * Returns true is a move is made and false 
  * otherwise.
  */

  public int generateComputerPlayerMove(ConnectFourPlayer computer)
  { 
    int column = computer.alphaBetaSearch(this);
    //update grid
    for(int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
    {
      if(board[row][column] == ' ')
      {
        board[row][column] = 'C';
        break;
      }   
    }
    return column;
  }
}
```

Comment: Unless you can do a little more debugging and troubleshooting on your own, you may get better answers at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the suggestion, but you are only allowed to post working code on that site. My question was put on hold because my code isn't working.